# Impact of sync function inside async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Lets imagine an asynchronous function that loads a file first and does something asynchronously with it afterwards. The function can't continue without the file, so my assumption is that loading this file could be done synchronously (*):

```
const asyncFnWithSyncCode(filePath, next) {

    // Load file
    const file = fs.readFileSync(filePath)

    // Continue to process file with async functions
    // ...

    next(null, processedFile)

}
```

`asyncFnWithSyncCode` could be called several times for different files:

```
async.parallel([
   (done) => { asyncFnWithSyncCode('a.json', done) },
   (done) => { asyncFnWithSyncCode('b.json', done) },
   (done) => { asyncFnWithSyncCode('c.json', done) }
], next)
```

My question is: How does this impact the performance? Will the sync function cause the other `readFileSync`s to be delayed? Will it have an impact at all?

Best-practices, resources and opinions are welcome. Thanks!

(*) I know that I could simply use the async `readFile`-version, but I would really like to know how it works in this special construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the sync function cause the other `readFileSyncs` to be delayed?

Yes. NodeJS runs all of your JavaScript code on a **single** thread, using an event loop (job queue), which is one of the reasons that using asynchronous system calls is strongly encouraged over synchronous ones.

`readFile` schedules the read operation and then lets other things happen on the JavaScript thread while the I/O layer is waiting for the data to come in; Node's I/O layer queues a task for the JavaScript thread when data is available, which is what ultimately makes your `readFile` callback get called.

In contrast, `readFileSync` holds up that one single JavaScript thread, waiting for the file data to become available. Since there's only one thread, that holds up *everything else* your code might otherwise be doing, including other `readFileSync` calls.

Your code doesn't need to use `readFileSync` (you almost never do); just use `readFile`'s callback:

```
const asyncFnWithSyncCode(filePath, next) {

    // Load file
    fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            // ...handle error...
            // ...continue if appropriate:
            next(err, null);
        } else {
            // ...use `file`...

            // Continue to process file with async functions
            // ...
            next(null, processedFile);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks a lot!